# Weighted Standard Deviation

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, standard-deviation

Hi I want to calculate weighted standard deviation in SQL Server 2012.

Is there any inbuilt function as of standard deviation in SQL Server or how to built a user define function in SQL Server.

Comment: I want Weighted Standard Deviation

Comment: possible duplicate of [weighted standard deviation in sql server without aggregation error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10947180/weighted-standard-deviation-in-sql-server-without-aggregation-error)

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in function (a similar question was [asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10947180/weighted-standard-deviation-in-sql-server-without-aggregation-error) by the way, although there is no accepted answer). Your most obvious options are:

- Write your own TSQL code
- Write a [user-defined aggregate function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190678.aspx) using .NET
- Do the calculation using a client application instead of the database

Answer (score -1):

There is - check out the documentation on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190474.aspx)

Example from MSDN:

```
USE AdventureWorks2012;
GO
SELECT STDEV(Bonus)
FROM Sales.SalesPerson;
GO
```

Here is another one to get you started 
http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/01/20/sql-server-introduction-to-statistical-functions-var-stdevp-stdev-varp/

Comment: That's standard deviation, not *weighted* standard deviation